# Stuck in KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, key-value-observing

I'm using the new Swift 4 API and I'm getting the `KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED` in a non-deterministic manner. Was anyone able to fix it? The code is pretty simple creating a KVO and storing it in a local variable.

```
private var rateObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

rateObservation = player.observe(\AVQueuePlayer.rate, options: [.initial, .new]) { (_, change) in
   observer(change.newValue)
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to observe on the _main_ thread. See: [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer). Also you need to deregister the observer when you're finished.

Comment: Also note that `rateObservation` needs to be optional!

Comment: Is `rateObservation` an instance property of the class? If it's only defined within a method like `viewDidLoad` it will stop observation once the function finishes execution.

Comment: I showed how I declared it. Please have a look.

Comment: @PranavKasetti's suggestion is where I'd start. Move the `observe()` call inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` block and see if it goes away.

Comment: I also added a log statement to ensure it is main thread and it was observed in the main thread and got the crash.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the documentation. Namely: `AVFoundation` invokes `observeValue` on the main thread always. But you have to _register_ I.e wrap the assignment of `rateObservation` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` block.

Comment: The log statement was before the registration not inside the callback. So  I'm 100% the registration itself is on the main thread.

```
print("IS MAIN THREAD: ", Thread.current.isMainThread)
        rateObservation = player.observe(\AVQueuePlayer.rate, options: [.initial, .new]) { (_, change) in
           observer(change.newValue)
        }
```

Comment: The other thing is you need to check is _unregistering_ in the main thread! Could you share this unregistering code too?

Comment: the deregistration is done automatically https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: You probably, need to read more about Swift 4 KVO which is broken by the way :)
I gave you an example https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html where they don't remove it

Comment: I can't find any official docs stating that other than the code itself here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L159 and if you read all blogs about swift 4 KVO, you will see the automatic removal of observations.

Comment: What about this blog?: https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4/blob/master/Whats-new-in-Swift-4.playground/Pages/Key%20paths.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L53-L95

Comment: Also, you can see from your link, that the new API wraps the old API `addObserver` in the `observe` function, and `removeObserver` in the `invalidate` function. Hence the old documentation is still valid!

Comment: I didn't say we should never use `invalidate` I said the swift docs & code and even the blog you pointed says "deiniting the object is the same as invalidating it"
I can't believe you don't believe the code https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L178

Try it yourself. Try to create observation and don't hold the object, you will see it the observation will be destroyed and you won't get any observation notification.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html): I believe this is what you mean. But the conditions for these relaxed requirements are not satisfied with AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't make sense to me. But it is the only way that made it work for me.

```
deinit {
    rateObservation?.invalidate()
}
```

Doesn't make sense because the documentation of the new observation clearly says that we don't need to unregister the notification and that works for almost most of the time but sometimes I got the mentioned exception and when I explicitly invalidated the observer it never throw the exception.

Comment: No. The docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-178612) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1408054-removeobserver) make it clear that you must make sure to deregister before deallocation. You won't get a repeatable error/exception, but these are Apple guidelines.

Comment: The first is an objective-c doc, the other is the old API.